# Google Says Postman is unsecure and therefore will not allow API connections

Tags: postman, google-oauth

I am trying to test out some Google OAuth2 connections, starting with a "Get a New Access Token" request.
[image]

when I click Request Token, It takes me to the google sign in page:
[image]

I go through that, then put in my password.  Once Complete, Google Squawks:
[image]

Is there a setting in POSTMAN that will allow me to execute this Correctly?
Thanks